# Codeigniter HMVC multiple urls loading same form what is best practice to handle this scenario

Tags: codeigniter, url, seo, hmvc, codeigniter-hmvc

I'm currently using HMVC with code igniter (i'm new to this), and I am trying to get a better understanding as how to best structure the urls for seo and best practice.

In an example I have a module Users (with mvc folders), one of the views is a login form:

```
<?php
        echo form_open('user/submit');
        echo validation_errors();

        echo "<p>Email: ";
        echo form_input('email');
        echo "</p>";

        echo "<p>Password: ";
        echo form_password('password');
        echo "</p>";
        echo "<p>";
        echo form_submit('login_submit', 'login');
        echo "</p>";    

        echo form_close();

    ?>
```

and the controller contains methods:

```
function login() {
    $data['view_file'] = "login_form";
    $this->load->module('template');
    $this->template->generic($data);
}



function submit(){

    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|xss_clean|valid_email');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|xss_clean');

    if ($this->form_validation->run($this) == FALSE){
        $this->login();
    } else {
      echo "Success";
    }
}
```

Now to access the form you go to the url:

http://somesite/users/login but when you click submit and the login has failed the user is redirected back to url: http://somesite/users/submit, how would this affect seo as the login form is accessible at both urls and what is best practice for this scenario?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I notice sth wrong with your description. when "login has failed the user is redirected back to url: http://somesite/users/submit", according to your script, user is redirected to url: http://somesite/users/login".
BTW, for SEO friendly, URL like http://site/controller/action are recommended.